# How do I update my .jsp files without restarting the whole JBoss server?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss

How do I update minor, tiny changes I've just made in a .jsp file, without restarting the whole JBoss server? This is just a private server on my (pretty slow) PC. Up until now, I've been able to click this little icon that says "restart module". Now, this icon is grayed out.

Comment: Do you definitely have to restart JBoss for a change to take effect? I'm not familiar with JBoss but if it's anything like Tomcat you don't - it will detect when a jsp page has been changed from the file's timestamp and recompile it on-the-fly

Comment: I don't _think_ it's a requirement, but right now nobody around me can figure out a way around it. JBoss wasn't exactly my first choice either.

Comment: So, if you just change the jsp file and then go to a URL that uses it (without restarting JBoss) do you see your change?

Comment: No, I definitely don't. I've tried saving, debugging, refreshing my client page of course (I know my PHP) but there's no luck via JBoss.

Comment: Are you making the changes directly in the jsp files on the server, or copying them across to it? If the latter, check that the server clock isn't ahead of the timestamp on your files - if it is then JBoss will think it doesn't need to recompile them

Comment: What version of jboss are you using? I'm only familiar with jboss 6.

Comment: I'm using JBoss 7.1 final, per my instructor's requirements.

And heck, the JBoss server is running straight out of Eclipse-- no console stuff. (At least, Eclipse is doing the server management.)

Comment: Well I normally use Glassfish with NetBeans and had a similar frustration with having to restart the server instead of use the integrated auto-deploy for some beans. I never did get it resolved but I think it has to do with quirks in how our IDEs integrate with these app servers. maybe try using and deploying outside of Eclipse to see if the issue still exist.

Comment: Presently I'm able to give my project The Finger (the "restart module" finger in the toolbar) to get it to work; I guess that's all I can really do right now. Re-debugging the program isn't really helping. **Edit:** Now I'm not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace your .jsp or the .war file for that matter. JBoss does a great job at detecting updated files and will redeploy and recompile your jsps.

Oh keep in mind your browser might be set to cache your files. in that case make sure to hit the refresh button or just open a fresh instance of your browser or tab.

Comment: For whatever reason JBoss finally kicked it into gear and started re-deploying modules properly. I realized, much to my chagrin, that I have to click off the editor view to click the Redeploy Package icon, and that having Build Automatically set helps things along tremendously.

Comment: This is not always true. In some situations (jsp included by other jsp's) jboss does not realise something's changed.

Answer (score 5):

I found that it does also help to configure the JSP Servlet to recompile on any change. This is not something you want in production, but it does speed-up development:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>modificationTestInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

as shown [in answer to 'JSP deployment without war file'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786798/1023341)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Web Servers support `Hot deployment and dynamic reloading`. Which extracts the WAR file within the server working directory. You can `replace your Modified JSP there to get picket at runtime`.

Possible duplicate . [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996977/jsp-deployment-without-war-file/10997149#10997149)